# Set default value to column when result is empty in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
$plan_expenses = DB::table('expenses_plans')
       ->Select([
       'opex_expense' => ExpensesPlan::select(
            DB::Raw('SUM(expenses_plans.jan + expenses_plans.feb + expenses_plans.mar + expenses_plans.apr + expenses_plans.may + expenses_plans.jun + expenses_plans.jul +expenses_plans.aug +expenses_plans.sep +expenses_plans.oct + expenses_plans.nov +expenses_plans.dec)')
            )
           ->where('division_id','1')
           ->where('country_id',Auth::user()->country_id)
           ->where('financial_year',Carbon::now()->year)
          
       ])

    //    ->addSelect([
    //     'local_staffex' => ExpensesPlan::select(
    //    DB::Raw('SUM(expenses_plans.jan + expenses_plans.feb + expenses_plans.mar + expenses_plans.apr + expenses_plans.may + expenses_plans.jun + expenses_plans.jul +expenses_plans.aug +expenses_plans.sep +expenses_plans.oct + expenses_plans.nov +expenses_plans.dec)'))
    //        ->where('division_id','2')
    //        ->where('country_id',Auth::user()->country_id)
    //        ->where('financial_year',Carbon::now()->year)
    //     ])
```

I have the above query with many `addSelect()`. It is my intention to set a default value if the result is empty as I want to avoid getting an empty collection of items[]. For example, if `opex_expenses` is empty it should return `zero` since this data may not always be available in the database.

Comment: FIRST: `select()`, NOT: `Select()`  --  

SECOND: `select('one','two', 'three')`, NOT: `select(['one', 'two', 'three'])`  --  

THIRD: what's means `->select(['key' => 'value'])` construct ?

Query works as is ? 

Please, fix that before.  Here Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries

Comment: FOURTH: `opex_expense` and `opex_expenses` are the same?   fix this typo too, pls?